# What is the difference between raw and jpeg images?

Tags: post-processing, raw, image-processing, photography-basics

I am a beginner at photography and I can’t really understand what a raw image is and how it is different from jpeg?
How is an image manipulated before processing?

Comment: There are several other existing questions/answers that are a lot closer to the intent of this question than the first suggested duplicate. I'll list a few of those in another comment.

Comment: [Why and how capturing RAW image instead of JPEG helps with editing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105080/15871) and [Why can software correct white balance more accurately for RAW files than it can with JPEGs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100925/15871) and [RAW in ACR vs JPG in ACR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85863/15871)